# XElement.Element failed to select the correct child node

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<inventory>
  <item>
    <stocktype>
      <type>Basket</type>
      <id>1</id>
      <parentId>0</parentId>
    </stocktype>
    <cost>10.00</cost>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <name>Golden Wick Basket</name>
    <note>
      <code>remark</code>
      <content>Be extra careful about the golden paint....</content> 
    </note> 
    <note>
      <code>usage</code>
      <content>DeluxFruitBasket</content> 
    </note>  
  </item>
  <item>
    <stocktype>
      <type>Fruit</type>
      <id>2</id>
      <parentId>1</parentId>
    </stocktype>
    <cost>6.00</cost>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <note>
      <code>remark</code>
      <content>Please pick red apples only</content> 
    </note>
    <note>
      <code>usage</code>
      <content>DeluxFruitBasket</content> 
    </note>
  </item>
  <item>
    <stocktype>
      <type>Fruit</type>
      <id>3</id>
      <parentId>1</parentId>
    </stocktype>
    <cost>4.00</cost>
    <quantity>10</quantity>
    <name>Orange</name>
    <note>
      <code>remark</code>
      <content></content> 
    </note>
    <note>
      <code>usage</code>
      <content>DeluxFruitBasket</content> 
    </note>
  </item>
  <item>
    <stocktype>
      <type>Fruit</type>
      <id>4</id>
      <parentId>1</parentId>
    </stocktype>
    <cost>12.00</cost>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <name>Pineapple</name>
  </item>
</inventory>
```

I have tried this LINQ to XML query but it always evaluated to false:

```
If(_rootElement.Descendants("item").Any(Function (x) x.Element("stocktype").Element("type").Value = "Fruit" And x.Element("note").Element("content").Value = "DeluxFruitBasket"))
```

and I have used linqpad to check and replace Any() with Where() and the query returned null.

Question:

- Why is the query returned null?
- I also discovered that x.Element("note").Element("content") will always select the first "note" element from the two, why?
- I can not change the structure of the XML as it is a standard in my company, how can I rewrite the query to archive my intent?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Why is the query returned null?"*

Because none of `item` element in your XML has *first* `content` equals `"DeluxFruitBasket"` (why it has to be the *first* `content` within `item` is related to question no 2)

> *"I also discovered that `x.Element("note").Element("content")` will always select the first "note" element from the two, why? "*

Because you use `Element()` instead of plural `Elements()`. The latter will return all matched elements as you intended.

This is one possible LINQ to get all `item` containing "Fruit" `stocktype` and at least one "DeluxFruitBasket" `content` (replace `Where` with `Any` to use this in your code) :

```
Dim result = doc.Root.
                 Descendants("item").
                 Where(Function(x) x.Element("stocktype").
                                     Element("type").Value = "Fruit" _
                                     AndAlso _
                                   x.Elements("note").
                                     Elements("content").
                                     Any(Function(c) c.Value = "DeluxFruitBasket"))
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CVCmZM)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks, Just read the MSDN  documentation again and I just realized it did say First (in document order) on top of the page. I always skipped that section of the page. No wonder I missed it.

Comment: Checked with linqpad and it works. Thank you very much!